# Firestore rules - Get specific field from document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My data of usercollection looks like this:

```
username: "johndoe"
email: "john.doe@test.com"
firstName: "John"
lastName: "Doe"
loginUid: "...."
```

and this is my rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I just want to read usernames from firestore, if not authenticated to check before registration, if username is already taken.
Is this possible. If not, is there another way, like creating a view of all usernames, which i could read from?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to check if a user document already exists before creating a new one.

A straightforward approach is to maintain a collection of documents with the user name as Document ID and set a security rule like the following one:

```
match /usersList/{userName} {
  allow create: if !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/usersList/$(userName));
  allow update, delete: if false;
}
```

This collection (`usersList`) can be the collection where you store the users. But it could also be a collection just dedicated to the verification and the users are contained in another collection.

In this last case you would use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to create the two docs, since batched writes are atomic: If the doc in the `usersListRef` collection already exists, the new `user` doc will not be created.

```
const userName = '....';

// Get a new write batch
const batch = writeBatch(db);

const usersListRef = doc(db, 'usersList', userName);
batch.set(usersListRef, { ... });

const userRef = doc(db, 'users', userName);
batch.set(userRef, { ... });

// Commit the batch
await batch.commit();
```